# Custom Event Dispatching

Tags: actionscript-3, event-handling, dispatchevent, custom-event

I'm trying to fire an event from sub class, I have 3 classes; EventHandler, MainClass, SubClass

**EventHandler.as**

```
    public class EventHandler extends Event
{
    public static const TEST_EVENT:String = "Test"; 

    public function EventHandler($type:String, $params:Object, $bubbles:Boolean = false, $cancelable:Boolean = false)
    {
        super($type,$params, $bubbles, $cancelable);
        this.params = $params;
    }

    public override function clone():Event
    {
        return new EventHandler(type, this.params, bubbles, cancelable);
    }

}
```

**MainClass.as**

```
        public function MainClass()
    {
        addEventListener(EventHandler.TEST_EVENT, testFunc);

    }


    private function testFunc(e:EventHandler){
        trace("OK");
    }
```

**SubClass.as**

```
private function CustomFunction(event:MouseEvent):void {
        dispatchEvent(new EventHandler(EventHandler.TEST_EVENT,customObject));

    }
```

I get VerifyError: Error #1063: flash.events::Event()
What's wrong with my architect? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, where's your `params` variable in your `EventHandler`? How does `this.params = $params;` compiles?

Comment: EventHandler is a bad chosen class name since an Event-class itself isn't the handler.

Comment: @Art is correct, the params field is missing.  But apart from that, you are misusing the term "event handler" to name a custom *event*, which can lead to all sorts of misunderstandings:  An *event* is dispatched from a *dispatcher, while a *handler* is the function that is called, when the event is received by a *listener* (it *handles* the event).

Comment: Defining the object "params" solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, I know the architect and naming is not OK but I couldn't find a source to build a well architect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `$params` from  `super($type,$params, $bubbles, $cancelable);`
Like this:

```
public class EventHandler extends Event
{
    public static const TEST_EVENT:String = "Test"; 

    public function EventHandler($type:String, $params:Object, $bubbles:Boolean = false, $cancelable:Boolean = false)
    {
        super($type, $bubbles, $cancelable);
        this.params = $params;
    }

    public var params:Object;

    public override function clone():Event
    {
        return new EventHandler(type, this.params, bubbles, cancelable);
    }

}
```

Comment: How to do it without "bubbling"

Comment: that is without bubbling its set to false by default, as is my example :)

Comment: But I can't dispatch this event from SubClass when it's false

Comment: This is the way you have to define your custom events. You can change number of arguments or their types, but everything else should be changed from dispatching and handling.

Answer (score 2):

Define a custom event like:

```
  package com.mysite.events 
  {
     import flash.events.Event;

    public class PendingEvent extends Event 
    {
    public var payload:Object = {};
    public static const CONTENT_COMPLETE:String = "contentComplete";

    public function PendingEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false) 
    { 
        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);

    } 

    public override function clone():Event 
    { 
        return new PendingEvent(type, bubbles, cancelable);
    } 


}

}
```

Elsewhere dispatch like:

```
    var event:PendingEvent = new PendingEvent(PendingEvent.CONTENT_COMPLETE);
    event.payload.someStuff = "stuff";
    event.payload.moreStuff = "moreStuff"
    dispatchEvent(event);
```

Then listen to it somewhere else:

```
    this.component.addEventListener(PendingEvent.CONTENT_COMPLETE, componentContentComplete);

    private function componentContentComplete(event:PendingEvent):void 
    {
                    // remove listener
        this.component.removeEventListener(PendingEvent.CONTENT_COMPLETE, componentContentComplete);

                    // do something useful with payload
        var payload:Object = event.payload;
                    trace(payload.someStuff); // stuff
                    trace(payload.moreStuff); // moreStuff
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Obvioulsy you would not use an `Object` for your payload, create another typed class of your choice and set props on that object instead, but you get the idea.

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't see a difference between my code and yours?

Comment: I removed the "params" parameter and it worked, but I need "params"